# Scala naming convention for options

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

When I return something of type `Option`, it seems useful to explain in the name of the function name that it is an option, not the thing itself.  For example, seqs have `reduceOption`.  Is there a standard naming convention? Things I have seen:

`maybeFunctionName`

`functionNameOption`

- neither seems to be all that great.

Comment: What about `functionNameOpt`? It's shorter and still descriptive.
Naming convention `maybe...` is probably more suited to Haskell, where the option type is called `Maybe`.

Comment: Just relax and forget about it. Soon you'll feel comfortable with member names not hinting about option, because in practice it's always obvious whether the member is able to return `None`. Consider this an adaptation phase

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`reduceOption` and friends (`headOption`, etc.) are only named that way to distinguish them from their unsafe alternatives (which arguably shouldn't exist in the first place—i.e, there should just be a `head` that returns an `Option[A]`).

`whateverOption` isn't the usual practice in the standard library (or most other Scala libraries that I'm aware of), and in general you shouldn't need or want to use this kind of Hungarian notation in Scala.

Answer (score 8):

Why would you want to make your function names longer? It doesn't contribute anything, as the fact that it returns an Option is obvious when looking at the function's type.

reduceOption is sort of a special case, since in most cases you really want to use reduce, except that it doesn't work on empty sequences.

Comment: "as the fact that it returns an Option is obvious when looking at the function's type."
...except, when the type is not actually made explicit, as Scala does not necessarily encourage specifying types explicitly.